# How to add detail views to table view?

Tags: ios, ipad, split

I hope someone can help me!

So I am building a app and I need to have 10 pages.
I found a way to order them in a way that suits the purpose.

I am using the template of this tutorial:
http://www.scienceathand.com/idevblogaday/adventures-in-uisplitviewcontroller-2/

The sample code is on github:
https://github.com/toddwbates/MultipleMasterDetailViews

So I have a split view, with the master view split in 2 by a tab bar. The master view contains a table. **The only thing I need to know is how I can add 4 detail view pages to the Master 1 table, and 6 detail view pages to the master2 table, working and navigating well.** So I can edit the pages individual and easy navigate to them.

The orientation of the app is: Landscape.

If you need more information, look at the tutorial, sample code or ask me the things you need to know to help me.

Comment: edited title and tags because it has NOTHING to do with xcode :) xcode is an IDE only :)

Comment: This is very vague. What have you tried so far?

Comment: It would help to try a few things first on your own prior to asking the community to solve your problem for you entirely. You're much more likely to receive direct and focused help that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you read up on the basics of `UIViewController` design and implementation. Here are a few links to get you started:

`UIViewController` Programming Guide:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html

Then when you've got a handle on that, check out the `UISplitViewController` documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISplitViewController

You could also refine your question by providing some examples of what you have tried that have not worked. This way the community would have a better idea of what you're trying to do.